# Wordpress code editor messed up my code!

Tags: css, code, wp-editor

I just spend a few hours trying to make my code look better. In the past, I did some changes using Wordpress code editor and after downloading these files yesterday, I noticed that code is totally messed up.

This is how code looks in the editor:
[image]

And this is how it looks in browser:

[image]

Needless to say, it's very annoying. Now I can't inspect given element in Chrome because it's giving mi false line number in code. Any ideas what can I do with this?

Comment: It may be annoying but it shaves off the needless bytes and increases download speeds. Except for the final semi-colon that is.

Comment: I know, but during the time when I was saving files locally and then uploading it to the server everything was fine. Now code is messed up and I can't edit it easily :/

Comment: TBH, you should have a mirror of your site stored locally this way you can quickly fix issues. Does it also strip the comments?

Comment: Does code look compressed in WP editor now? Caching plugins like to minify code at output.

Comment: In WP editor it looks almost identically as in the browser screenshot. I don't use any caching plugins on this site.

Comment: Do you have any minification or "code optimisation" plugins active? Any SEO plugin could as well be the issue.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't as good as line numbers but you can add a dummy class every so often.

```
#_________section_1 {
    display: none; /* Just in-case it strips the empties */
};
```

It may help you to quickly scroll to the relevant section. To be honest though, you should have a mirror of your site stored locally and only change the online version when you're 100% satisfied.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Yes, I have original file on hard drive, but it's outdated and I must do couple of changes. I was just looking for a simple solution to convert messed up by Wordpress file ;)

Comment: If you just want to convert then use a text editors search and replace. search = '{' replace = '{\n' etc.

Comment: This is exactly what I have done. Code that you are seeing on screenshoots is already after some corrections, one of them was '{\n' in Notepad++.

Comment: The problem is - I can load old files, but I did some changes since them and having messed up file it will be difficult to even see changes and compare them.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend to use **Notepad++ with built-in FTP connection** (built-in nppFTP addon). It made my life easier after I've started using that. Never touched WP-EDITOR already for years now.